# Using Active Directory user for running a command in container

Tags: linux, docker, active-directory, containers, uuid

I am trying to run a JUnit Test in a Linux container. The code is on a shared area and the test results are written to shared area. The problem I faced was that container not able to write files to the shared area. I fixed by updating the permission to RWX for all users(777).

Now the test results container writes to that area has different permissions(-rw-r--r-- 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody). And the other user is not able to operate over these test results.

I want to run the test in a container with an Active Directory user so that whatever it writes from container, the files is accessible/permissible to the same user from outside. Any idea how to achieve it?

Comment: Can you share dockerfile ?

Comment: You can try to run test in container, generate reports in side containers and then run ` docker cp test:/report .` after copying reports you can terminate the container. So the file being copied this step will be accessible to the current user